# Insert a line into a file using fileinput.input

Tags: python

I want to insert a line into the middle of a text file that I have.

I have tried:

```
for line in fileinput.input('file.txt', inplace=1):
    if line.startswith('example'):
        print 'input line'
```

which worked. But I wanted this to loop over many files, so I changed it to:

```
for line in fileinput.input('{0}' .format(file), inplace=1):
    if line.startswith('example'):
        print 'input line'
```

and I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "addline.py", line 8, in <module>
    for line in fileinput.input('{0}' .format(file), inplace=1):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 253, in next
    line = self.readline()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 322, in readline
    os.rename(self._filename, self._backupfilename)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I would like to know why this doesn't work and any suggestions to fix would be appreciated.

Comment: your problem seems to be `file` doesn't exist, which the error shows. what is `file`? is that a filename or a directory?

Comment: It's a file in a folder. But when I change {0} for the actual filename it works. I thought there must be a problem using {0} with fileinput.input. I'll check everything again.

Comment: The problem is `file` is a reserved name in Python, try using another name like f, and you should be fine

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in this line:

```
for line in fileinput.input('{0}' .format(file), inplace=1):
```

change to this:

```
# f is the filename
for line in fileinput.input('{0}'.format(f), inplace=1):
```

First problem, change `file` to other name, `file` is a reserved name in python.

And, make sure you're passing a `list` of filenames if you were trying to pass multiple files.

Try changing to this:

```
...
files = ['file1', 'file2', ...] # put your files in a list first
# and pass the list of files to .input
for line in fileinput.input(files, inplace=1):
...
```

Comment: @user1551817, that's fine and I'm glad it helps :)

Comment: How is `'{0}'.format(string)` ever going to be different from just `string`?  Or maybe `str(thing)` if the thing you were passing to `format` was not already a string.

Comment: @tripleee, well you're right its kind of redundant in this case, but the issue OP had just wasn't about string formatting, it's more about the file didn't exist in the first place. But yeah, your point is valid.